# Restarting application does not pick up updated properties from git

Tags: spring-cloud, configserver

I recently upgraded our application to Spring Boot 2.3.3 , Spring Cloud 3.1.5 and also updated our config server to Spring Cloud Config Server from Config Server.

The application is working fine but I am having issue with picking up properties from git repo if any are updated.

Earlier before I updated our Spring versions and config server, whenever I change the property value in properties file in git and restart the application, the app picked up the latest updated property.

But now with the upgrades, when I update the property and restart the web-app, its still not picking up the updated property. Found a workaround for now that I need to synchronize mirror refresh in Spring Cloud Config Server and then restart the app and the updated property value is picked up by the app.

But wanted to know if there is a solution for this instead of the work around so that it works like it used to earlier. I tried many ways but nothing works. I had the actuator dependencies and also property value set to refresh already set in my app. But they are not working. Please let me know how to proceed with this issue.

Comment: please rephrase your actual question

Comment: Hi..updated the config server to spring cloud config server ..so with the update config server refresh is not working as expected..for any change in the properties to take place we had to manually do a synchronize mirrors and then restart the app in pcf ..wanted to know if there is a better way to do it..before the update we just had to restart the app in pcf for the changes in property to take place..

Comment: What is `Config server`? Let's show few lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is that you did not use ***periodic:true*** in JSON file for your Spring cloud config. Once you add it, It will refresh the config properties after every 5 mins automatically as mentioned in spring cloud config server documentation here - https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/3-1/common/config-server/refreshing-properties.html

*"you can use the periodic parameter when configuring a Config Server service instance to cause the mirror service to automatically refresh a Git repository mirror periodically"*

Read more about Periodic here - https://docs.pivotal.io/spring-cloud-services/3-1/common/config-server/configuring-with-git.html